# Scala: conforming concrete type to generics with bounds

Tags: scala, generics

I've defined a function with generics and I have some trouble understanding the error that the compiler is giving me. The problem can be expressed simply with :

```
def myfunc[T <: MyClass](param:MyClass):T = param
```

It gives me this error on `param` in my the body : Expression of type MyClass doesn't conform to the expected type T.

Why? `param` fits the upper bound of T. How can I make something like this work without resorting to casting param to T?

Answer (score 9):

Ok. Assume, you have the below:

```
class Animal
class Dog extends Animal
```

And now lets have your function below:

```
def myfunc[T <: Animal](param:Animal):T = param
```

For now assume, compiler doesn't throw error. On calling `myfunc[Dog](new Animal)`, it should return a `Dog` according to function definition. But In reality, you are just sending back `Animal`. Which should not be allowed. Hence the error.

Now had it been:

```
def myfunc[T >: Dog](param:Dog):T = param
```

Here on calling `myfunc[Animal](new Dog)`. The return type is of `Animal`. But the function returns a `Dog` which is correct as `Dog` is an `Animal`. Hope it clarifies

Comment: The clearest answer on the whole page. Breath of fresh air given the example with animals rather than `T`s and `U`s.

Answer (score 4):

You have the variance backwards. If `T <: MyClass`, then you can supply a `T` where `MyClass` is expected. But you cannot give a `MyClass` where `T` is expected.

To illustrate:

```
def myfunc(x: Any): String = x
```

This gives the same error, for the same reason. An `Any` is not a `String`, and your `MyClass` is not a `T`.

This is what you may have meant:

```
def myfunc[T >: MyClass](param:MyClass):T = param
```

Which works fine.

Comment: Yes, but no. I don't want T to be a supertype of MyClass. I really want T to be a subtype. However, I realized that the return type cannot be T, since T could be any subtype of MyClass and the runtime type of `param` also could be a subtype of MyClass, and they don't necessarily match.

Comment: Try pretending that Scala does not have subtyping, and figure out the requirement from there. Then reintroduce subtyping if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

```
class A(); class B extends A;

scala> def myfunc[T <: A,U >: A](param: U):T = param
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
found   : param.type (with underlying type U)
required: T
       def myfunc[T <: A,U >: A](param: U):T = param
```

Your `param:MyClass` does really have a lower bound (`>: MyClass`), like in Java - it can be any descendant of `MyClass`. So, how could you run `myfunc(B)` and return type that is higher on class diagram than `A`? B considered lower than A in an inheritance diagram, you return B but say that it is really `<: A`. Error.

Sometimes its useful to explicitly declare all those types like, T, U, V etc and see what compiler says.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that *param* relates to *T* because they share a common ancestor is wrong.

For example, a base class *A* can have two subclasses *B* and *C*. If *T* is of type *B* and *param* is of type *C*, *param* is not of a type relatable to *T*.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help you.

The argument type is T not MyClass.

```
object StackOverFlow13851352 extends App {
    class MyClass
    class YourClass extends MyClass
    def myfunc[T <: MyClass](param: T): T = param

    val clazz: YourClass = myfunc(new YourClass)
}
```

Scala code runner version 2.10.0-RC2 -- Copyright 2002-2012, LAMP/EPFL

java version "1.7.0_09"

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that, but that's not the point. I want to know why the compiler refuse to understand that `param`'s type conforms to T.